# Foreach MySQL Join by Category

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

**How to foreach from join database for show Foods by its Category.
Thank you. **

How to select from database with join to foreach the results by category.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM categories;
+-----+-----------------+
| id  | categories      |
+-----+-----------------+
| 1   | Oven            |
| 2   | Pizza           |
| 3   | Salad           |
| 4   | Starter         |
| 5   | Coffee          |
| 6   | Softdrinks      |
+-----+-----------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM foods;
+------+----------------------+--------+--------------+
| id   | name                 | price  | category_id  | 
|+-----+----------------------+--------+--------------+
| 1816 | Acini                | 15     | 1            |
| 1817 | Wedding Soup         | 11     | 1            |
| 1818 | Pasta Campanelle     | 12     | 4            |
| 1819 | Chicken Noodle Soup  | 12     | 6            |
| 1820 | Pizza Valtellina     | 12     | 5            |
| 1821 | Cedar Planked Salmon | 11     | 3            |
| 1822 | Italian Sausage Soup | 12     | 3            |
| 1823 | Pasta Pappardelle    | 10     | 1            |
+------+----------------------+--------+--------------+
```

Please how the MySQL code for join the tables.

And the results should like below

```
$results = [
    'Oven' => [
        ['name' => 'Acini', 'price' => '15'],
        ['name' => 'Wedding Soup', 'price' => '11'],
        ['name' => 'Pasta Pappardelle', 'price' => '10']
    ],
    'Starter' => [
        ['name' => 'Pasta Campanelle', 'price' => '12']
    ],
    'Softdrinks' => [
        ['name' => 'Chicken Noodle Soup', 'price' => '12']
    ],
    'Coffee' => [
        ['name' => 'Pizza Valtellina', 'price' => '12']
    ],
    'Salad' => [
        ['name' => 'Cedar Planked Salmon', 'price' => '11'],
        ['name' => 'Italian Sausage Soup', 'price' => '12']
    ]
];
```

Please help.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM categories JOIN foods on foods.category_id=categories.id;```

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "db_name");
$result = [];
$sql = 'SELECT foods.name, foods.price, categories.categories FROM foods JOIN categories ON categories.id = foods.category_id ORDER BY categories.categories';
$data = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $result[$row['categories']][] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'price' => $row['price']) ;
}
//output
var_dump($result);
```